# Java method called from XSLT returns String with double quotes arount it

Tags: xslt, saxon

When I call simple Java method (returns plain String) from XSLT it always returns String with double quotes around it, Is there a way to prevent it?

```
<message><xsl:value-of select="msg:formatMsgByLang($msg-formatter, $lang,  $tmpParams)"/></message>
```

And what I get back is:
    "Success"
instead of 
    Success

Edit:
I'm using Saxon 9.0.0.8 XSLT processor, and this is taken out from a huge legacy xslt and I will try to extract reproducable piece of xslt/java code.

Comment: Consider to provide minimal but complete samples of XML, XSLT and Java to allow others to reproduce that, together with precise information of the XSLT processor you use. Whether and how an XSLT processor interacts with Java (passes XSLT values to Java and converts Java values to XSLT values) is completely dependent on a particular processor.

Comment: It's not the behaviour I would expect, but (a) Saxon 9.0 is over 10 years old and therefore tricky to investigate, and (b) there's not enough information here to try and reproduce it.